# Replacing strings while keeping punctuation

Tags: python-2.7

I have a task to write a program that replaces words like Noun, Place, PluralNoun etc.. with the word "corgi". I got the code 90% right but I'm missing the punctuation but I don't know why. Here is the code I wrote:

```
parts_of_speech  = ["PLACE", "PERSON", "PLURALNOUN", "NOUN"]

test_string = """This is PLACE, no NOUN named PERSON, We have so many PLURALNOUN around here."""

def word_in_pos(word, parts_of_speech):
    for pos in parts_of_speech:
        if pos in word:
            return word
    return None

def play_game(ml_string, parts_of_speech):   
    replaced =[]
    word=ml_string.split(" ")
    for w in word:
        print w
        con = word_in_pos(w,parts_of_speech)
        if con != None:
            replaced.append(w.replace(con,"corgi"))
        else:
            replaced.append(w)
    return " ".join(replaced)

print play_game(test_string, parts_of_speech)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`word_in_pos()` is returning the argument `word` in its entirety, including any punctuation in it. So when you do your `replace()`, you're also replacing the punctuation. Instead, just return `pos` from `word_in_pos()`:

```
def word_in_pos(word, parts_of_speech):
    for pos in parts_of_speech:
        if pos in word:
            return pos
    return None
```

Result:

> This is corgi, no corgi named corgi, We have so many corgi around here.